# How to add button to call java method

Tags: java, wicket

I have tried to code at below, but the java **onSubmit()** seems not get called. I also tried to add **onclick** to the button and called to a method but it still not get called

reschedule.java

```
WebMarkupContainer rescheduleContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("reschedule");

Button addRescheduleBtn = new Button("addReschedule"){
     @Override
     public void onSubmit() {
         final Item i = getJtrac().loadItem(globalItem.getId());
         Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
         long timeInSecs = date.getTimeInMillis();
         Date rescheduleDateTime = new Date(timeInSecs + (20 * 60 * 1000));
         i.setNextExecutionTime(rescheduleDateTime);
         i.setStatus("ready");
         getJtrac().updateItem(i);
     }
 };

 addRescheduleBtn.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
 rescheduleContainer.add(addRescheduleBtn);
 add(rescheduleContainer);
```

reschedule.html

```
<form>
<div class="space-below" wicket:id="reschedule">
    <input type="submit" wicket:id="addReschedule" class="btn btn-primary" wicket:message="value:item_view.reschedule"/> 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Link` with overwriting `onClick` instead? Your button is embedded into a form, but since you never create a `Form` inside the java code wicket doesn't know how to handle the submit and just ignores it.

Comment: Try adding a `wicket:id` to form, then create a `Form` in your Java code. Next, add the button to the form component in java.

Comment: Check wicket documentation https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/9.x/single.html#_wicket_forms

Comment: I see. I will try to implement the "Form". Is there any alternative to click on the button and called to the java method?

Comment: @magicmn already explained the alternative: use a `Link`

Comment: And if you want to react through Ajax, you need to add an AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior (https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.html) to you Button.